# How to move, resize or remove KDE widgets since Plasma 5.5.5 (xenial)

Tags: kde, 16.04, plasma

Until Plasma 5.4.2 (wily) widgets could be unlocked and showed a side menu when hovering over them with the mouse. The side menu allowed moving, resizing and removing the widget. With Plasma 5.5.5 (xenial) the side menu does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

With Plasma 5.5.5 the menu appears after a long left-click (instead of hovering with the mouse in Plasma 5.4.2). This can be changed back in Desktop Settings (right click on desktop) -> Tweaks -> Widget Handling. This solution was first posted on [bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359220).

Comment: And the user hostile nutters in Plasma have struck again. Widgets can't be moved either with the crazy long left or any other way.   It's 2018 and UX is two letters of the alphabet that mean nothing to the Plasmoids.  Widgets can be locked and unlocked, but you can't drag a widget even when it's unlocked.

Comment: Hello Warren, thanks for your comment. Do you think that you can create a new question for this issue specifying which version of Plasma is affected? Maybe someone will be able to find a workaround. By the way, did you check the options under Desktop Settings?

Comment: I too find Plasma a bit counter-intuitive. Having said that, widgets can be moved once the menu is shown by hovering on the menu away from the visible icons. A fist-like mouse cursor appears. Drag as needed. Still... an icon with 4 arrows...

Comment: right-clicking a widget should also bring options for its settings and for removing it.

Comment: It is a little insane to screw up basic functionality like this. I have not been able to move widgets after 10 mins of trying and this is totally unacceptable. I know you guys feel like you have to constantly add new features, but why can't you leave normal working simple functionality in peace? The new KDE is a backstep to what we had years ago. JUST STOP MESSING WHAT DOES NOT NEED FIXING!!!

Comment: This is really bad UX... the "long left click" is a kludge to replace the right click on touchscreens, but most people won't expect it to work with the mouse. If they want to use the long left click, it should either do the same thing as the right click, or at least what the long left click does should also be available in the context menu which is shown on right click.

Comment: Now that I took a closer look, i found that the long-click functionality _is_ also available via the context menu (under "Customize Layout") - however when using the "sticky notes" widget like I was, right-clicking in the text edit area shows the text editing options, you have to click on the border or the toolbar to get the widget options...