# Resize Desktop icons and widgets in kubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: kubuntu, icons, resize

on my new laptop I installed the latest LTS of kubuntu (16.04).

After adding some widgets and program shortcuts to the desktop I found that I am not able to rizise the widgets and icons (which are really large)

My old Computer I was running kubuntu 14.04. There could change the size by hovering the cursor over the icon and then selecting resize in the "popup" [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483560/how-to-move-icons-on-kubuntu). This popup isn't showing in 16.04 (the widgets are unlocked). Also in the context menu I found no resize option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution...

With Plasma 5.5.5 the menu appears after a **long left-click** (instead of hovering with the mouse in Plasma 5.4.2). ([found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761138/how-to-move-resize-or-remove-kde-widgets-since-plasma-5-5-5-xenial))

... question to myself: Why were there no results during my search before I posted.